# Need advanced help, Wordpress & mailchimp

Tags: php, wordpress, url, download, mailchimp

Heyhou!

I have tried to figure this out long time already, but no luck so far.
I have Wordpress site with mailchimp email form, so users are able to join my email list. The problem is:
 -When user join the list, Mailchimp send automatically the confirmation email. I have edited it already to meet my requirements, but I need one more thing. I need to place URL where the joined user can download my free file, that URL needs to be one time url and it would redirect to my site where s/he can download the file.

Soooo, which way would be a best way to do that ? The main point is here that nobody can't start share the download link or page so users could download the file without to join my list. Poor English, hope you got the picture.

I'm web developer / PHP programmer, so plug in is not a must, (of course if you know one, let me know) I can make this by myself, but I need your help to solve the logic, how this would be done.

If I just place my website's download link in the Mailchimp confirmation email, there isn't anything which protect file. I need to somehow to crush the link after user is downloaded the file. BUT no manual changes in Mailchimp confirmation email.

There might be some super easy solution for this or not, anyway I'm stuck.

Thank ya!

Comment: What did you try? And what kind of file is the download? Maybe u can create the file already and let it be an attachment in the mail.

Comment: seriously ? why somebody vote down without saying anything, would be awesome if there is something what i'm missing.

Comment: PDF file, I have only tried figured the logic out how I can make this working. I'm stuck, whit that how I can protect the file

Answer (score 0):

I have used mailchimp previously and found the only way to push some data into an email, for this example a dynamic URL with a special access code is to set it as an extra bit of data on the users profile via the API.
http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/manage-subscribers-with-the-mailchimp-api/

From when I last used Mailchimp you get 30 fields of custom data you can set on each user.

Hope that helps.